# Mysql service not getting started on start up on some pc with windows 10

Tags: mysql, iis-7, application-pool, ncalc

I am facing issue on both windows 10 pro and windows 10 home single language version.
First of all the mysql service is not being started automatically and moreover I am forced to restart/recycle application pool for my ncalc.dll to work properly to evaluate formulaes.

Regarding Ncalc.dll. The formula is not being evaluated and throwing an error on deployed code on IIS, but when I restart the application pool associated with it, the formula starts to get evaluate.

I am stunned with the issue and I am not able to replicate it on my my windows 10 copy. The issue is being occurred only on both versions of windows specified but not on all windows 10. The hardware configuration where the issue is being generated(2 different pc) are both **Dell Core i5 8265U CPU 1.60GhZ**. Both the machines are running on same configuration.

For 1 PC the issue was not there with previously with Ncalc(application pool) but was there with Mysql from start but from yesterday it is coming for mysql as well as Ncalc(application pool)

Can somebody please help me with the issue. Is it related to some recent windows update or the hardware or with windows 10 primarily. I have tried lot of permutations but not able to replicate at my end. Has someone faced a similar issue previously?

Comment: 1. Start microsoft management console (MMC), add "services" and see if windows service for mysql has StartType=Automatic. 2. Also in MMC see if event viewer has error entries.

Comment: Posting your error log would probably be helpful for consideration from one machine.  This is a one question/one answer oriented web site to simplify problem resolution.

Comment: Hi All, for more debugging into the issue. I create a batch file, created shorcut, gave administrative privileges, placed it in CMD--> shell:startup folder. But when i shutdown and start the file is not running. Same thing I tried on different computers with both windows 7 and windows 10 and the file ran successfully on startup. *So now the issue comes down to why the startup services are not running on windows with this hardware config specified above*. Will this analysis help you further to give me root cause and solutions of the issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Posting your error log would probably be helpful for consideration from your one failing machine. This is a one question/one answer oriented web site to simplify problem resolution, once you post the error log.  If we can not see the error log, then it is anyone's guess with no foundational information.